# Differentiate time exceeded from no server response using HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

Is there a way, using HttpClient, to differentiate a time-out "when we get no response from the server" from a "time exceeded" operation?

Let me explain our issue:

- Case1: If we don't get any response from the server in 10 seconds then this is an issue.
- Case2: If we get a response from the server, but the server continues to transfer data and it takes a while, maybe 30 seconds or more. Then this is not an issue.

Is there a way using .NET HttpClient class to handle this scenario? From what I tested specifying a TimeOut on HttpClient will put the same time-out for case1 and case2.

Comment: is the server and/or service under your controller? can we extend it/change config?

Comment: Yes, but here the goal is to change how the client works. If we don't get any feedback from the server in 10 seconds (no headers, nothing at all) then we consider that the client has a "temporary" connectivity issue and we should stop. If we get a feedback from the server, then that's ok, the server can take a lot of time to transfer all data (it can be even more than 1 minute).

Comment: I believe from HttpClient you can get the underlying request object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I managed to do:

```
// Create the cancelation token, when we don't get any feedback from server within 20 seconds
var cancelHeadersToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancelHeadersToken.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); // if we don't receive server headers after 20 seconds then something went wrong

// We have another cancelation token, that allows the user to cancel the request, so here we create a linked token source which uses both tokens
var linkedToken = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(userCancelToken, cancelHeadersToken.Token);

// The linked token is then used in GetAsync and we use the overload which allows to specify the HttpCompletionOption
// We only want to receive headers and not all content
var httpMessage = await customClient.CustomizedHttpClient.GetAsync(address, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, linkedToken.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

// We can then download the content, and we still allow to cancel anything by the user
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(100000)) { // 100ko by default
    using (var stream = await httpMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream, 10000, userCancelToken).ConfigureAwait(false); // copy to memory stream 10ko per 10ko
    }

    string data = "";
    if (memoryStream.Length > 0) {
        var headers = httpMessage.Content.Headers;
        Encoding encoding;
        if (headers != null && headers.ContentType != null && headers.ContentType.CharSet != null) {
            encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(headers.ContentType.CharSet);
        } else {
            encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        }
        data = encoding.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }
    // Then you do whatever you want with data
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you downvote? Everything is detailed with nice comments... and it totally solves the question that I was asking...

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but - where in all that code is the answer to the question? Half of the code (reading the content) seems to be irrelevant. Plus: misnaming things (a tokensource is NOT a token), a complex way to create a single token without explaining why, missing definitions (what's that userCancelToken ?)

Comment: I will try to improve the quality of the response today. It's hard though since having only 2 lines of code won't explain much... that's why I have put the whole block here and added comments inside it.

Comment: You can try words and describing why this is a solution.

Comment: There is a nice solution here for differentiating between user canceled and timeout canceled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the variants of the various methods that accepts a `CancellationToken`.

If the cancel happens *after* the method's `Task` has completed, the cancellation is ignored and you can continue with e.g. processing the content from the result.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancel.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var resp = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.co.uk", cancel.Token).Result;
```

So, in the above, provided we get enough back from the server for the `GetAsync` to complete, the cancellation has no effect.

Comment: Of course, you should still add some more timeouts along the way, just to make sure it actually does something. Also, don't forget that web response is usually buffered - it may very well be that the web server only sends the entire response at once, or that it only sends data every 4 kiB.

Comment: Hi Damien Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure this is a valid answer to my problem: in our case client.GetAsync("http://www.google.co.uk", cancel.Token) will take more than 10 seconds. The server will transfer data for at least 30 seconds. Therefore, if during 10 seconds, we don't get anything at all, then in that case it is an issue.

Comment: @Fabien - then that means that the server is not even sending out the *headers*. If that's the case, then there's no way, from the **client** side, to distinguish between cases 1 and 2.

Comment: It's not a server issue that we want to solve in fact. Imagine your client can't connect to the server due to network issues. If we don't get any feedback from the server in 10 seconds (no headers for example) then we consider that the client has a "temporary" connectivity issue and we should cancel. If we get a feedback from the server then the general timeout, for the whole operation, should be 1 minute.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever any idea based on my previous comment?